# FileNotFound error when trying to download a file in django website

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

in my `index.html` I create a link to download a file

```
<ul>
    {% for fil in listFiles %}
    <li><a href="{{ fil.csv_file.url }}" download class="btn btn-dark float-right"> {{ fil.csv_file.name }} </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

the `listFiles` object is generated from this model

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class CsvDFile(models.Model):
    csv_file = models.FileField()
    file_path = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    userID = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In the html page the url is like this `<li><a href="/uploads/test.csv" download class="btn btn-dark float-right"> test.csv </a></li>`

However, when I click on it I get this error `Not Found: /uploads/test.csv`

I checked the folder and the file is in there and the folder 'uploads' is inside my app directory
Also in `settings.py` I set `MEDIA_URL = 'uploads/'` and `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/uploads')`

The var `BASE_DIR` is referencing to  my project directory
in `settings.py` `BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent`

And my `urls.py` looks like this

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [..My views..]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)
```

I don't know why it's not recognizing the file

Comment: ```MEDAI_ROOT```?  Is this just a typo while posting or is that actually the env var?

Comment: @ewong sorry, I edited it

Comment: I'm a little confused with your ```/uploads/test.csv``` in the href and your ```MEDIA_URL = 'uploads/'``` Is it looking for ```/uploads/test.csv```  or ```uploads/uploads/test.csv``` or ```myapp/uploads/test.csv```?

Comment: the CsvDFile() model should store the files at the location specified by MEDIA_ROOT var right?
so when ever this model create new file object it is stored in that location, however, csv_file.url prints out this in the href tag '/uploads/test.csv', then it tries to find this path but it can't

Comment: Perhaps, as a test,  can you create an ```uploads/uploads/test.csv``` file?  And then see if you can download it?   These references to ```myapp/uploads/test.csv```, ```uploads/``` and ```/uploads/test.scv``` is confusing me, of which I apologize.

Comment: first you could try directly in browser different URLs (with domain) like `http://.../uploads/uploads/test.csv` to see which one will work.

Comment: I think you should use `MEDIA_ROOT` instead of `MEDIA_URL` in `document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT`  in full line `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`. Even [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) uses `MEDIA_ROOT` instead of `MEDIA_URL`